# How to combine list of list with anyone common element in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have merge two list of list with one common element in python.

for example I have below list of list:

```
[[1.0, 'Software Developer', 1256],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1329],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1469],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 2086],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1256],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1329],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1469],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 2086]]
```

and My Desire output as follows:

```
{'ID': 1469,
 'Location': 'United States',
 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231,
 'title': 'Software Developer',
 'title_score': 1.0}

{'ID': 1256,
 'Location': 'United States',
 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231,
 'title': 'Software Developer',
 'title_score': 1.0}
```

This is sample output I want to do for all.

Can anyone please tell me how to merge all common Element which are last  in all List. and then Convert List in Dictionary.

I tried to use `'Union'` function. and Did some google but I haven't got proper answer.

Can anyone please help me in it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your data is  lists in list it's IMO not possible to find out if, for example, the first element is a "title_score" or a "location_score". I would suggest to prepare your data in two lists:

    `titles = [[1.0, 'Software Developer', 1256],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1329],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1469],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 2086]]

    locations = [ [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1256],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1329],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1469],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 2086]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [[1.0, 'Software Developer', 1256],
       [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1329],
       [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1469],
       [1.0, 'Software Developer', 2086],
       [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1256],
       [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1329],
       [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1469],
       [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 2086]]

# initialize defaultdict of dicts
d = defaultdict(dict)

# calculate half length of list
n = int(len(lst)/2)

# iterate first part of list
for title_score, title, ID in lst[:n]:
    d[ID]['title_score'] = title_score
    d[ID]['title'] = title

# iterate second part of list
for Location_score, Location, ID in lst[n: len(lst)]:
    d[ID]['Location_score'] = Location_score
    d[ID]['Location'] = Location
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(dict,
            {1256: {'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231,
                    'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0},
             1329: {'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231,
                    'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0},
             1469: {'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231,
                    'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0},
             2086: {'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231,
                    'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0}})
```

If you need a list of dictionaries, you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [{**{'ID': k}, **v} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. It is very useful and same as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using collections.

```
data = [[1.0, 'Software Developer', 1256],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1329],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1469],
 [1.0, 'Software Developer', 2086],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1256],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1329],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1469],
 [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 2086]]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    d[i[-1]].extend(i)
res = []
for i in d.values():
    res.append({"ID": i[-1], 'title_score': i[0], 'title': i[1],'Location_score':i[3], 'Location': i[4]})
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States', 'ID': 1256, 'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer'}, {'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States', 'ID': 1329, 'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer'}, {'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States', 'ID': 1469, 'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer'}, {'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States', 'ID': 2086, 'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a plain dict, assuming only that the "title" records come first:

```
>>> lol = [[1.0, 'Software Developer', 1256],
...  [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1329],
...  [1.0, 'Software Developer', 1469],
...  [1.0, 'Software Developer', 2086],
...  [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1256],
...  [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1329],
...  [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 1469],
...  [0.9230769230769231, 'United States', 2086]]
>>> 
>>> keys = [(gr + '_score', gr, 'ID') for gr in ('title', 'Location')]
>>> 
>>> out = {}
>>> for L in lol:
...     d = out.setdefault(L[-1], {})
...     d.update(zip(keys[bool(d)], L))
... 
>>> out # dict of dicts
{1256: {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 1256, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}, 1329: {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 1329, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}, 1469: {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 1469, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}, 2086: {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 2086, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}}
>>> list(out.values()) # list of dicts
[{'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 1256, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}, {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 1329, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}, {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 1469, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}, {'title_score': 1.0, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'ID': 2086, 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231, 'Location': 'United States'}]
```

Or---if dict order matters (Python 3.6+ inofficial, Python 3.7+ official):

```
>>> out = {}
>>> for l in lol:
...     d = out.setdefault(l[-1], {})
...     d.update(zip(*map(reversed, (keys[bool(d)], l))))
... 
>>> out
{1256: {'ID': 1256, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0, 'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231}, 1329: {'ID': 1329, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0, 'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231}, 1469: {'ID': 1469, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0, 'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231}, 2086: {'ID': 2086, 'title': 'Software Developer', 'title_score': 1.0, 'Location': 'United States', 'Location_score': 0.9230769230769231}}
```